# Accept Android app permission without user interaction

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, embedded

I'm working on an embedded app that uses Android Tv os. The app needs the camera to scan Qr code, Now I have to accept the camera permission but I can't make any actions
on the app.

Is there any solution to accepting the permission programmatically and without rooting the device?

Thank you.

Comment: You can only grant permissions through adb but debugging needs to be enabled and you need access to the device.

Comment: You want an app to generate an permission without user interaction? Wouldn't this foil the purpose of permissions?

Comment: Can I grant permission with adb from Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not. The idea of permissions system is to ask user for permission. You can ask on the start of application and not allow to run app if user don't accept it.